# Zend _forward() does not work in preDispatch()?

Tags: php, zend-framework, execution-time

Im currently building a controller from my Zend MVC application which would only be used as json service to populate the page. I want to restrict the users to use only GET method to access this end point(for some security reasons).

I followed this post [_forward() in Zend does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749619/forward-in-zend-does-not-work) but could not get working.

I am using the preDispatch to detect the non-get requests and would like to forward to errorAction in the same controller. My code looks likes this,

```
public function preDispatch(){
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    //Restrict this Controller access to Http GET method
    if(!($this->getRequest()->isGet())){
        return $this->_forward('error');
    }
}

public function errorAction(){
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(501);
    echo "Requested Method is not Implemented";
}
```

When I test the page with a post request, it throws

> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

I got it working with

```
$this->_redirect("service/error");
```

Wondering if it is the only/best way to handle this situation.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that calling `_forward` doesn't work is because the request method doesn't change so you end up in an infinite loop trying to forward to the `error` action since the request is always `POST`.

`_forward` works by modifying the module, controller, and action that will be called when the request is dispatched, `_redirect` actually returns a 302 redirect and results in an additional HTTP request by the browser.

Either method is okay, but I'd prefer to go with `_forward` since it won't require an additional HTTP request (but you still guarantee the `POST` request is denied).

This code should work for you:

```
    if(!($this->getRequest()->isGet())){
        // change the request method - this only changes internally
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET';

        // forward the request to the error action - preDispatch is called again
        $this->_forward('error');

        // This is an alternate to using _forward, but is virtually the same
        // You still need to override $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] to do this
        $this->getRequest()
             ->setActionName('error')
             ->setDispatched(false);
    }
```